# NGINX Multiple reverse proxies

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two NodeJS backends running on port 3000 and 4000 in a ubuntu server with NGNIX installed.

I don't have any domain names but I want to use nginx as a reverse proxy with my IP address like this.

- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app1 => should forward all the requests to port 3000
- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app2 => should forward all the requests to port 4000

This is what I tried in NGINX configs, but it returns 404 not found response.

In /etc/nginx/sites-available directory, I have modified default as this,

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

How can I make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not run `sudo service Nginx reload`. This command reloads the changes made in the configuration file. Check, If it's still not working do the following things:

Create a file `myproxy.conf` with the below content:

1.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

2. Run `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproxy.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`
3. Run `sudo service nginx reload`

You should be able to proxy servers.

**NOTE**

- Servers context should start with app1 and app2 respectively.
- If using `myproxy.conf` remove `default` from `/etc/nginx/site-enabled`

**Important**

A request URI is passed to the server as follows:

- If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a [normalized](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) request URI matching the

  location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:

  `location /name/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
  }`
- If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:

  `location /some/path/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
  }`